# Does there exist research about equation like $u_{tt}=\det(D_{x}^{2}u)+\cdots$?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, reference-request

Does there exist research about equation like $$u_{tt}=\det(D_{x}^{2}u)+\cdots$$? That is to say, it contains second order time term $u_{tt}$ and the determination of Hessian of solution $\det(D_{x}^{2}u)$. Recently, I have read some papers concerning Hyperbolic meaning curvature flow like the paper"The hyperbolic mean curvature flow" by K.Smoczyk and philippe G.Lefloch on JMPA. But does there exist some research like the above question, if yes, can you offer me some paper? Thank advance.